# Python Regex To Ignore Date Pattern

Tags: python, regex

**Sample Data:**

```
Weight Measured: 80.7 kg (11/27/1900 24:59:00)
Pulse 64 \F\ Temp 37.3?C (99.1 ?F) \F\ Wt 101.2 kg (223 lb)
Weight as of 11/11/1900 72.2 kg (159 lb 1.6 oz)
Resp. rate 16, height 177.8 cm (5' 10"), weight 84.7 kg (186 lb|
11.2 oz)
And one extra weight example 100lbs
```

**Partially working Regex:**

```
\b(?i)(?:weight|wt)\b(?:.){1,25}?\b(\d+\.?(?:\d+)).*?(\w+)\b
```

**Current output:**

```
('80.7', 'kg'), ('101.2', 'kg'), ('11', '11'), ('84.7', 'kg'), ('100', 'lbs')
```

**Expected ouput:**

```
('80.7', 'kg'), ('101.2', 'kg'), ('72.2', 'kg'), ('84.7', 'kg'), ('100', 'lbs')
```

How do I make my current regex ignore dates and capture the value that follows?
Also, how do I make this regex to stop matching at the end of line?

Comment: you should add the expected output as well.

Comment: Remove the dates before running your regex. It's a simple, failsafe pattern.

Comment: Don't intend to modify the data in any form or factor!

Comment: Does the measurement unit always comes after the number separated with whitespace?

Comment: No. It can also be like '100lbs'; without any white spaces. But yes, unit will always come after the number.

Comment: Ok, so nothing or whitespace. Use `r'(?i)\bw(?:eigh)?t\b.{1,25}?\b(?<!\d/)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!/?\d)\s*(\w+)'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That worked on my sample data. Let me try it out on a larger set. Will it also stop matching at the end of line !?

Comment: Well, `\s` can match newlines, replace with `[^\S\r\n]` to only match horizontal whitespace

Comment: _Don't intend to modify the data in any form or factor!_ How does removing the dates count as modifying the data, but extracting part of it doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'(?i)\bw(?:eigh)?t\b.{1,25}?\b(?<!\d/)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!/?\d)\s*(\w+)', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/leug8Z/1)

**Details**

- `(?i)` - same as `re.I` - case insensitive mode on
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `w(?:eigh)?t` - `wt` or `weight`
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `.{1,25}?` - any 1 to 25 chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\d/)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if immediately to the left of the current location there is a digit and `/`
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a dot and one or more digits
- `(?!/?\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if immediately to the right of the current location there is an optional `/` and a digit
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more letters, digits or underscores.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/H3QIht):

```
import re
text = """Weight Measured: 80.7 kg (11/27/1900 24:59:00)\nPulse 64 \F\ Temp 37.3?C (99.1 ?F) \F\ Wt 101.2 kg (223 lb)\nWeight as of 11/11/1900 72.2 kg (159 lb 1.6 oz)\nResp. rate 16, height 177.8 cm (5' 10"), weight 84.7 kg (186 lb|\n11.2 oz)\nAnd one extra weight example 100lbs"""
print(re.findall(r'(?i)\bw(?:eigh)?t\b.{1,25}?\b(?<!\d/)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!/?\d)\s*(\w+)', text))
# => [('80.7', 'kg'), ('101.2', 'kg'), ('72.2', 'kg'), ('84.7', 'kg'), ('100', 'lbs')]
```